# Ender 3 Pro: Parts cooling fan making strange noises

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-fan

I am using an Ender 3 Pro that I bought near the end of March 2023, and I have not modified any of its parts. About an hour ago, I tried preheating the hotend (using the 'Preheat PLA End' setting) and heard a buzzing sound coming from the parts cooling fan.
I tried cleaning the fan and made sure it was connected properly, which made the noise a bit quieter but didn't make it go away.

- What is causing this noise?
- Can it be fixed without replacing the fan?
- If so, how?

I will keep trying to understand and fix the problem, and will add updates if I find more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - What is causing this noise?
> - Can it be fixed without replacing the fan?
> - If so, how?

The sound was caused by a buildup of filament near the motherboard and in the motherboard fan. After getting rid of the strands, the part cooling fan has stopped making the buzzing noise.